# How to Create Global Header for all pages in html(5)?

Tags: html, header, include, global

I have created an HTML page 'header.html'.  Then I need to implement the same header on about, services, contact page.

I know that we can do it via PHP Include.  But as an HTML Developer, Is there any way to use like this in HTML without using third party code, especially in HTML 5?

Also I came to know that Dreamweaver has an option to make templates file. But I don't know is it valid in Web 3.0 and W3c.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either a server-side language like PHP or Server Side Includes, or you use something like Dreamweaver which will assemble HTML files for you from parts which you then upload to the server. You cannot do it browser-side using HTML only.

Comment: whats your opinion on using jQuery to insert such blocks of code like PHP? I've noticed with these porting apps they will only accept static html files, so you can't use PHP, which is strange, its like we're going backwards in time